# Magento 1.9 rest api developer documentation

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to create rest api for magento 1.9 but I am unable to find any developer documentation for the same.
Please if some could refer me some sites so that I can refer and implement rest api's and oauth for magento 1.9 version.

Answer (score 3):

For Magento 1 and OpenMage dev docs, you can go to:

- https://r-martins.github.io/m1docs/guides/m1x/
- https://devdocs-openmage.org/guides/m1x/

Answer (score 0):

Magento has removed API references for 1.X. You can try to get it from here https://github.com/OpenMage/devdocs-m1